# How to cleanly, computationally efficiently compare offsetted short time series?

Tags: time-series, correlation

I have a large number of short time series (assume 10 points).
There are two subsets of them:

One subset is sampled at t = 0,10,20,30,40,50,

the other is sampled at t = 3,13,23,33,43,53.

(This is just an example. The shift could be 1..9 in this case, i.e. 0, 10, 20 to 1,11,21 or 8,18,28)

Sampling frequency is the same, but they are offset.
Of course in a first approximation I can ignore the time shift since x[t] and x[t+1] are relatively similar; or I could interpolate both to get a series 0,3,10,13 etc. Is there any better way?

Actually I am mostly interested in the similarity of one "master" time series (sampled at 0,10,20) to 2x100 series (100 being sampled at 0,10,20 and the other 100 at 3,13,23).

(As you might have guessed, the application is chromatographic peaks.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you suggest, linear interpolation is likely the most computationally efficient way to compute estimates for your time shifted time series.

Any other method would require looking at more data points to impute the points at 0, 10, 20, 30, so while might provide better estimates, will be computationally less efficient. It really depends on the variance in your time series.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer, even though it really restated your first question. ;-)

Re-reading your question, you really want to determine _the similarity of one "master" time series_. Perhaps you want to look at time series distance measures that don't require time series to be aligned. Have a look at dissimilarity measures such as:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping